# Displaying multiple columns from a single column in same row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have to show id, type and value (in three different columns) in single row for each id from the table having id, name and vale as columns as below.

Original table

```
ID  NAME    VALUE
1   Effort  10
1   Type    Development
2   Type    Testing
2   Effort  20
3   Type    Testing
3   Effort  20
```

Expected:

```
ID  TYPE           VALUE
1   Development 10
2   Testing         20
3   Testing         20
```

And following is the query i used to achieve the expected result:

```
select id as id, 
case name when 'Type' then value else null end as TYPE,
case name when 'Effort' then value else null end as value 
from tmn;
```

But I am getting a slightly different result form my expected one as:

```
ID  TYPE           VALUE
1              10
1   Development 
2   Testing 
2              20
3   Testing 
3              20
```

Mates, As i mentioned earlier, please help to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me  know that satisfies you

```
SELECT  t1.ID,
        t1.Name,
        t2.Value
FROM    tmn As t1
        Left Outer Join tmn As t2
            On t1.ID = t2.ID
            And t2.Name = 'Effort'
WHERE   t1.Name = 'Type'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code sample to obtain the desired results:

```
declare @test table (id int, name varchar(25), value varchar(25))

insert into @test (id, name, value)   
select 1,'Effort','10' union all
select 1,'Type','Development' union all
select 2,'Type','Testing' union all
select 2,'Effort','20' union all
select 3,'Type','Testing' union all
select 3,'Effort','20'

select t1.id, t2.value, t1.value
from (select id, value from @test where name='effort') t1
join (select id, value from @test where name='type') t2 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Edit: This code sample assume you have a effort/type entry for every id.  If not, you may need to change to a full outer join, but will then possibly get null values back.

An alternate select statement would be:

```
select t1.id, t2.value, t1.value
from @test t1, @test t2 
where t1.name='effort'
and t2.name='type'
and t1.id=t2.id
```

Comment: also is it possible to get the unique type values and the sum as like below 
`ID  TYPE           VALUE
1   Development     10
2   Testing         40`